# How to write a Fabric script that uncomments a particular line of a user's .bashrc file?

Tags: python, bash, fabric

How would you write a Fabric script that uncomments the line

```
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

from the logged-in user's .bashrc file?

Note: This question is specifically about editing this particular line, not about simply appending force_color_prompt=yes to the end of the file and ignoring this line.

Comment: can't you use `sed` for that?

Comment: If you'll use sed: `cat .bashrc | sed -e 's/\(force_color_prompt=yes\)/\#\1/g'`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

fabric do have api for that. `fabric.contrib.files.uncomment`

```
from fabric.contrib.files import uncomment
uncomment("~/.bashrc", "^#force_color_prompt=yes", char='#')
```